# Shape key mesh problem

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, shape-keys

I was using a shape key for the finger joint, I thought it worked but then a new issue showed up. When I go into object mode the mesh looks fine but in edit mode it looks ugly like a wort. Is there a way to fix this?[image]

Comment: There are any number of potential causes, including but not limited to other modifiers, shapekey value, other shapekeys, etc.  If you link a file, I'm sure that people would be able to tell you what's happening, but otherwise I doubt you'll get any help.

Comment: How do you link, I never tried that.

Comment: You upload a file to a hosting site and post the link in the question.  Recommended hosting for Blender SE is https://blend-exchange.com/